# the hashchange event of jQuery doesn't work if I open a page with hash directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I placed a script tag at the end of a html page:

`$(window).on ('hashchange', function (e) { alert (location.hash); });`

It works if I click on buttons with hrefs like `#a`, but If I open links like `localhost/aaa#a` the alert function is not triggered.

So it looks like I have to detect the presence of a hash when the document is ready. But that looked wrong.

Is there a way to make it work in both situations?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to trigger the event manually on page load. The event will only get triggered when there is a direct action from the user.
Since it is page load with no action from the user the on hashchange event will not get triggered.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    alert(location.hash);
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

If you want to fire the event only when there is a hash value then

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    alert(location.hash);
});

if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange')
}
```